# How to get the Azure Data Disk Type i.e. HDD/SSD?

Tags: azure-disk

Could you please Help me to get the Disk type also for azure managed disks. Below I am only getting Premium_LRS and Standard_LRS. But I also required Whether the disk is ***"HDD or SSD"*** also.

```
$Disks = Get-AzureRmDisk -ResourceGroupName $RG.ResourceGroupName  | select Name,ResourceGroupName,Sku

foreach ($Disk in $Disks) {
$Name = $Disk.Name
$RG = $Disk.ResourceGroupName

$Final = Get-AzureRmDisk -ResourceGroupName $RG -DiskName $Name | select Name,ResourceGroupName,ManagedBy

$VM = $Final.ManagedBy


$vmrg = $Final.ResourceGroupName

$VmName = ($VM -split '/')[8]

$Type = (Get-AzureRmDisk -ResourceGroupName $RG -DiskName $Name).Type.GetType

Write-Host -Separator "                     ” $VmName $VMsize $vmrg $Final.Name $Type

}
```